# Docker Connection Refused when joining Swarm on internal network

Tags: docker

I am able to ping IPs between two machines on an internal network. However, when I try and join a Swarm, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp n.n.n.n:nnnn: connect: connection refused"
```

where `n.n.n.n:nnnn` is obviously the IP and PORT of the Swarm Manager (per `docker swarm join-token worker`).

I've searched but have been unable to find any information on further configuration I need to do on the Swarm Manager to resolve this issue (most likely because I'm not sure what to search on).

Does anyone happen to know how to resolve this? Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the following in a [Docker Swarm doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/):

`Currently, you cannot use Docker Desktop for Mac or Docker Desktop for Windows alone to test a multi-node swarm, but many examples are applicable to a single-node Swarm setup.`

Since I'm running the Master and Worker on two Mac computers, it looks like I'm out luck for now.